# Between operation for date in SQLite database 

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table `student` with the following columns:

```
no - integer
name - string 
startdate - date 
enddate - date.
```

Date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

I will give a date as input. Now I need a query the `inputdate` which found in between the start and end date.

For an example I will give `04/14/2012`, then the query should return the 1st record as in the figure.

(because input date (`04/14/2012`) is found in between the `04/10/2012` to `04/20/2012`)

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the SQL query where you are comparing dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is caused by your assumption that sqlite has a date/datetime type when in fact it doesn't.

I suggest you read the following http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html to have a better understanding of sqlite types.

The dates in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format are handled as TEXT by sqlite, and so those dates are compared as strings. For example, `02/01/2012` is considered bigger than `01/02/2012`by sqlite if compared directly.

You will need to transform those dates to a format that can be string-compared. Here is an example:

```
sqlite> create table foo (d TEXT);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('02/01/2012');
sqlite> select substr(d, 7, 4) || substr(d, 1, 2) || substr(d, 4, 2) from foo;
20120201
```

Answer (score 2):

You should post what you have tried so far.

There should be a `between` clause that you can use:

```
select * from table
where inputdate between startdate and enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates as a date type in SQLite don't exist.  There are a number of approaches to dealing with dates - store them as integer seconds since 1 Jan 1970 (unixepoch) or store them as strings, but if you do, then you really need to store them in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format because that is what the date functions require as input.

Assuming you use the string format in the format I suggested then your query would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date(Inputdate) BETWEEEN Date(startDate) AND Date(EndDate);
```

(although you may want to format the output of the date columns to US date format with

```
SELECT Strftime("%m/%d/%Y",startDate) As StartDate ...
```

If you use seconds since 1970 its somewhat easier because the seconds just compare without needing the convert them to dates, although you still might want to output in US date format, so ...

```
SELECT Strftime("%m/%d/%Y",startDate) As StartDate ... FROM Table WHERE inputDate BETWEEN startDate and EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite> select *from tbl_node where mydate between '2014-02-02' and '2014-02-06';`

it show the output :-

```
1|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:00:44
2|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:01:03
3|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:00:57
4|1|123|456|12eb-ab|1|1|254|123|19|2014-02-03 16:00:34
```

Here mydate is column name in tbl_node;
we can also use from current time , using now.

`sqlite> select *from tbl_node where mydate between '2014-02-02' and 'now';`